# When to Ask Captcha Rules?

Tags: security, captcha, ddos

While there is a lot of discussion about Captcha implementation, I couldn't find any details on what circumstances one should ask for Captcha especially for a financial app serving consumers.

Some of the rules I think of:

1. If 3 failed login/registrations attempts
2. If 3 duplicate calls if user already logged in.

I believe these rules are driven through security risk and is there a better way to manage this? Any library, which helps to solve this problem?

Comment: Comment: Key question is how to manage these rules? Static hard-coded in code or manage it some other way? Any software library which might help in this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, in situations like this, you'll always have to make a compromise somewhere between security and convenience.  I think the specific number you chose are fine; a human *probably* won't do those things and if something does, it's *probably* not a legitimate user.  I would suggest that after you start to require CAPTCHAs to continue, you also continue counting those cases and log an alert at some point and eventually ban the IP address if their actions get out of hand.

One place you'll have to compromise is on how you track users.  If you do it by cookies, it will be more accurate, but a bot can just not send cookies in most cases, eluding your tracking.  The only real solution, then, is to track by IP addresses.  The problem with this is that any users behind a shared IP address would look the same, so if three users all fail a single login, it would look the same (mostly) as one users failing three times.  Also, if someone gets legitimately banned for abusing your site and is behind a shared IP address, it is possible that other legitimate customers could be affected.

To sum it up, you'll need to find the balance you need between security and convenience.

Comment: Banning by IP address or by user can lead to a denial of service attack against a person or an entire network. Just implement the captcha.

Comment: @MarcusAdams That's why I say he needs to find a balance.  If someone is abusing the site from one address, it should probably be banned, but he'll have to consider the potential effects to other users.  And I only suggest banning the IP address after significant abuse, not just a few incorrect passwords.

Comment: Banning Ip Address is not going to work as many users come through the same Ip address depending on the country.